# How can I correctly display all the elements of 2D array that have even neighbors?

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement

I wrote a program that finds and displays all the elements in the 2D array, which have all neighbors(left, top, right, bottom) - even. I tried to put in an if, but the result is wrong. I think because it checks for non-existent elements, if the current element is on the edge. How can I fix it? Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define n 5
#define m 9

int main()
{
    int i, j;

    int array[n][m] = {
            {-1, 4, 12, 2, 10, -1, 8, 7, 6},
            {18, 3, 2, 0, 0, 10, 10, 0, 0},
            {9, 18, 3, 12, 5, 18, 4, 7, 0},
            {6, 3, 11, 5, 11, 1, 1, 1, 22},
            {8, 7, 46, 20, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    };

    // int m,n;
    // printf("Rows and Columns: \n");
    // scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

    // int array[n][m];

    // printf("Enter elements: \n");
    // for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    //   {
    //           for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    //           {
    //                scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
    //            }
    // }
    printf("Matrix: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf(" %3d", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Elements with all neighbors even are: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if ((array[i-1][j] % 2) == 0 && (array[i+1][j] % 2) == 0 && (array[i][j-1] % 2) == 0 && (array[i][j+1] % 2) == 0)
            {
                printf("a[%d][%d]= %2d\n",i,j, array[i][j]);}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you know the answer. *"I think because it checks for non-existent elements, if the current element is on the edge"* -- so if the element is on the edge, don't check for non-existent elements.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Sorry, I mispronounced the question. Even if the element is on the edge and has only 3 neighbors, for example, but they are even, I have to display it anyway.

Comment: `(i == 0 || (array[i-1][j] % 2) == 0)` the element to the left does not exist or it is even. Adapt to the other 3 cases.

Comment: You can handle this through a chain of positive statements (an element is selected if all of the following is true) or a chain of negative statements (an element is eliminated if any of the following is true). Consider an element `E_nm` with neighbors `E_(n-1)m`, `E_(n+1)m`, `E_n(m-1)`, and `E_n(m+1)`. 1. What must be true for the element to possibly be selected? 2. What must be true for the element to definitely be eliminated?

Answer (score -1):

first, you have to check for **particular element of array** that **neighbor exists or not** by applying condition as shown in below code and then you have to check for the **even number**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define n 5
#define m 9

int main()
{
    int i, j;

    int array[n][m] = {
            {-1, 4, 12, 2, 10, -1, 8, 7, 6},
            {18, 3, 2, 0, 0, 10, 10, 0, 0},
            {9, 18, 3, 12, 5, 18, 4, 7, 0},
            {6, 3, 11, 5, 11, 1, 1, 1, 22},
            {8, 7, 46, 20, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    };

    // int m,n;
    // printf("Rows and Columns: \n");
    // scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

    // int array[n][m];

    // printf("Enter elements: \n");
    // for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    //   {
    //           for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    //           {
    //                scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
    //            }
    // }
    printf("Matrix: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf(" %3d", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Elements with all neighbors even are: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if( n==1 && m==1 ){
                printf("No neighbour exist");
            }

            else if( i==0 && j ==0 ){
                if ((array[i+1][j] % 2) == 0 && (array[i][j+1] % 2) == 0)
                printf("a[%d][%d]= %2d\n",i,j, array[i][j]);
                
            }
            else if( i==0 && j == (m-1) ){
                if ((array[i+1][j] % 2) == 0 && (array[i][j-1] % 2) == 0)
                printf("a[%d][%d]= %2d\n",i,j, array[i][j]);
            }

            else if( i== (n-1) && j==0 ){
                if ((array[i-1][j] % 2) == 0 && (array[i][j+1] % 2) == 0)
                printf("a[%d][%d]= %2d\n",i,j, array[i][j]);
            }

            else if( i== (n-1) && j==8 ){
                if ((array[i-1][j] % 2) == 0 && (array[i][j-1] % 2) == 0)
                printf("a[%d][%d]= %2d\n",i,j, array[i][j]);
            }

            else if( i == 0 ){
                if ((array[i+1][j] % 2) == 0 && (array[i][j-1] % 2) == 0 && (array[i][j+1] % 2) == 0)
                printf("a[%d][%d]= %2d\n",i,j, array[i][j]);
            }

            else if ( j == 0 ){
                if ((array[i+1][j] % 2) == 0 && (array[i-1][j] % 2) == 0 && (array[i][j+1] % 2) == 0)
                printf("a[%d][%d]= %2d\n",i,j, array[i][j]);
            }

            else if ( j == ( m-1 ) ){
                if ((array[i+1][j] % 2) == 0 && (array[i-1][j] % 2) == 0 && (array[i][j-1] % 2) == 0)
                printf("a[%d][%d]= %2d\n",i,j, array[i][j]);
            }

            else if ( i == (n-1) ){
                if ((array[i-1][j] % 2) == 0 && (array[i][j-1] % 2) == 0 && (array[i][j+1] % 2) == 0)
                printf("a[%d][%d]= %2d\n",i,j, array[i][j]);
            }

            else 
            {
                if ((array[i-1][j] % 2) == 0 && (array[i+1][j] % 2) == 0 && (array[i][j-1] % 2) == 0 && (array[i][j+1] % 2) == 0)
                printf("a[%d][%d]= %2d\n",i,j, array[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, lets say that `n` and `m` are set to `1`, do your proposition still work ? Why writing `4`, `8` in your condition ? Your code is overcomplicated and bugged, sorry.

Comment: then take it as a variable (n-1) and (m-1) as it represents the maximum index in array.

Comment: @Tom's can you show me an alternative to this code?

Comment: @Tom's its showing right output....

Comment: @Viral Gajera if n = 1 and m = 1, then your first if condition is true (`( i==0 && j ==0 )`) but your inner if condition do an out of bound access  `if ((array[i+1][j] % 2) == 0 && (array[i][j+1] % 2) == 0)` => `if ((array[1][0] % 2) == 0 && (array[0][1] % 2) == 0)`. With n = 1 and m =1, your array goes up only to `array[0][0]`.

Comment: @RataDaniel mch comment gave you the solution. do a double for loop, then you do 4 if (left / rigth / up / down).

Comment: @Tom's I have corrected the solution for n==1 and m==1, check if works, or kindly give suggestions for another improvement

Comment: Suggestions? Just follow [mch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72217166/how-can-i-correctly-display-all-the-elements-of-2d-array-that-have-even-neighbor#comment127593020_72217166)'s one: https://godbolt.org/z/cTMoE768z

Comment: @ViralGajera what if n = 1 and m = 2 for instance ? Still bugged :D You have to try to simplify your algorithm. Your algorithm, in english, should sound like "if any of the for neighbore are not even, you don't print it". Bob__ solution is one way to do it. I think your bigger algorithm mistake is to try to treat i and j at the SAME time. Treat them separatly : "if the left cell exist and is not even" or "if the left cell doesn't exist or if is even" shouln'd have the up/down/rigth cell in the condition at all.